# Polymer 1.0 Layout Migration- vertical?= equivalent?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In polymer 1.1,

Does anyone know if there is a equalivant to

```
<div layout vertical?="{{mediaQuery}}"
       horizontal?="{{!mediaQuery}}">
```

in polymer 1.0? `class$={{foo}}` doesn't do it as far as I can see. For instance, something like `class$="vertical$={{mediaQuery}}"`

Answer (score 1):

Actually `class$="{{foo}}"` should work. But `<div layout` wouldn't 'cause the `layout` is now a *class selector* in Polymer `^1.0`. So you will need to write something like `<div class="vertical layout">` to make it work.

Since now string concatenation is **not** supported, in order to make the *selectors* dynamic, you need to use a *computed binding* -

```
<div class$="{{_computeLayoutClass(mediaQuery)}}">

_computeLayoutClass: function(mediaQuery) {
  if (mediaQuery) {
    return 'vertical layout';
  }
  else {
    return 'horizontal layout';
  }
}
```